# Array merge to multidimensional by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Iam having trouble with solving merging of array to multidimensional array.

My array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_Sinoskysun International (HK) CO., LTD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_RUTRONIK Elektronische Ba
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_TTI
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_ARROW CENTRAL EUROPE GMBH
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_TDK
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_YANGZHIDING ELECTRONICS
        )
     [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41301
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-302.01
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 5% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => 
        )
     [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24526
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-097.04
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_TDK
        )
)
```

And i need to merge them like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Array
            (
                "Pro_Sinoskysun International (HK) CO., LTD",
                "Pro_RUTRONIK Elektronische Ba",
                "Pro_TTI",
                "Pro_ARROW CENTRAL EUROPE GMBH",
                "Pro_TDK",
                "Pro_YANGZHIDING ELECTRONICS"
            )
       )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41301
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-302.01
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 5% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => 
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24526
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-097.04
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_TDK
        )
)
```

Input array can be 5 or 500 items and i need to merge them by ID.. There is just one thing different from each other and its who made them. Is it somehow possible?

If something more is needed i can add it. :)

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I will say that it can be done, and it would not even be that hard. You will have to iterate over the firts array and add element to their respective places in second array during the iteration of the first

Comment: @NigelRen yep i've.. also i've tried to looking on stack for answers too but nothing from it was working as i wanted.. :( Iam learning by myself so its lil harder for me to solve things by myself.. I tried it for few hrs but with no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will produce your desired output, regardless of whether the array has different id values. This code **does** assume that all similar products are grouped in order though:

```
$output = array();
$i = -1;
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($i < 0 || $output[$i]['id'] != $arr['id'] || $output[$i]['regNumber'] != $arr['regNumber'] || $output[$i]['name'] != $arr['name']) {
        // new product
        $output[++$i] = $arr;
        $output[$i]['madeBy2'] = array($arr['madeBy2']);
    }
    else {
        // same product, new manufacturer
        $output[$i]['madeBy2'][] = $arr['madeBy2'];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0m0S7)

**Alternate version** Only makes `madeBy2` element into an array if there are multiple values:

```
$output = array();
$i = -1;
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($i < 0 || $output[$i]['id'] != $arr['id'] || $output[$i]['regNumber'] != $arr['regNumber'] || $output[$i]['name'] != $arr['name']) {
        // new product
        $output[++$i] = $arr;
    }
    else {
        // same product, new manufacturer
        if (!is_array($output[$i]['madeBy2'])) 
            $output[$i]['madeBy2'] = array($output[$i]['madeBy2'], $arr['madeBy2']);
        else
            $output[$i]['madeBy2'][] = $arr['madeBy2'];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Array
            (
                "Pro_Sinoskysun International (HK) CO., LTD",
                "Pro_RUTRONIK Elektronische Ba",
                "Pro_TTI",
                "Pro_ARROW CENTRAL EUROPE GMBH",
                "Pro_TDK",
                "Pro_YANGZHIDING ELECTRONICS"
            )
       )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41301
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-302.01
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 5% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => 
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24526
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-097.04
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Pro_TDK
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/f6uUB)

Comment: That's it.. Output is not what you wrote but i can work with it.. :)
Thanks a lot for help.

Output https://pastebin.com/NB1bCGD2

Comment: @DanielSymphoWeiss You're right... pasting output from 3v4l is a pain so I copied yours. :-P but I've added an alternate solution which will only convert `madeBy2` into an array if there are multiple values so it does give you that output.

Comment: one more question.. If i want to add description to row in array madeBy2 how can i do it?

Comment: @DanielSymphoWeiss I can't see where description is coming from? It might be better if you asked a new question using this answer as a starting point and adding the additional information. On the upside you can gain additional rep by accepting another answer!

Comment: ah okay :) i wont spam so better to ask here :D gimme sec

Comment: anyway if you want to prep.
Array
        (
            .....
            [madeBy2] => Pro_TDK
            [desc1] => C1608X7R1E104K080AA
            [desc2] => 
        )

i need to add that desc1 and 2 to madeBy2

[madeBy2] => Array
            (
                "Pro_Sinoskysun International (HK) CO., LTD", "C1608X7R1E104K080AA", "",
                "Pro_RUTRONIK Elektronische Ba",
                "Pro_TTI",
                "Pro_ARROW CENTRAL EUROPE GMBH",
                "Pro_TDK",
                "Pro_YANGZHIDING ELECTRONICS"
            )

Comment: its here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370834/upgrade-of-array-merge-to-multidimensional-by-key :) thanks a lot

Comment: and i've found solution finally.. :D so closed :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. I was just starting to look at it when you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I build up an array which is indexed by the `id` value from the data, if it's not already set then I create a new element with the data - although `madeBy2` is created as an array.  If the element already exists, then it adds the new value to the existing list of values ( using `[]`)...

```
$out = [];
foreach ( $inp as $data )   {
    if ( isset ($out[$data['id']])) {
        $out[$data['id']]["madeBy2"][] = $data["madeBy2"];
    }
    else {
        $out[$data['id']] = [ "id"=>$data['id'],
            "regNumber" => $data['regNumber'],
            "name" => $data['name'],
            "madeBy2" => [$data['madeBy2']]];
    }
}
print_r(array_values($out));
```

This will leave an array indexed by the `id` so I use `array_values()` in the `print_r()`, you can leave it in if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in code

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if(!isset($output[$arr["id"]])){ // if item does not exist
        $output[$arr["id"]] = $arr; // create array
        $output[$arr["id"]]['madeBy2'] = [$output[$arr["id"]]['madeBy2']]; // change type on madeBy2 to array
    }else{    
        $output[$arr["id"]]['madeBy2'][] = $arr['madeBy2']; // it item exist add madeBy2 to the list
    }
}
$output = array_values($output); // remove associative array keys.
print_r($output);
```

This method does not rely on the list being sorted and only madeBy2 is hardcode.
Meaning if one array has an extra item this method will keep it opposed to Nigel's.
Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41844
            [regNumber] => CSM-057.05
            [name] => 100nSMD060310%X7R25V
            [madeBy2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Pro_SinoskysunInternational(HK) CO.,LTD
                    [1] => Pro_RUTRONIKElektronischeBa
                    [2] => Pro_TTI
                    [3] => Pro_ARROWCENTRALEUROPEGMBH
                    [4] => Pro_TDK
                    [5] => Pro_YANGZHIDINGELECTRONICS
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41301
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-302.01
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 5% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24526
            [regNumber] => P+CSM-097.04
            [name] => 100n SMD 0603 10% X7R 25V
            [madeBy2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Pro_TDK
                )

        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/iCjk1

Demo with extra item:
https://3v4l.org/0jmpL